# Python SQLite3 syntax error when creating a table

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a table with the following command:

```
'CREATE TABLE users_profile(user_id INTEGER UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,\
    firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, email TEXT, website TEXT,\
    picture TEXT, mobile TEXT, skype TEXT, age INTEGER, residence TEXT, gender TEXT,\
    signature TEXT, avatar TEXT)'
```

I get the error: 'Error near "firstname": syntax error:'

I know that the following part is causing this error: 'FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE'

So apparently I'm doing something wrong here, but I just can't figure out what I need to change in order to make this work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you need to escape the '\'?

Comment: I don't think the backslashes cause any problems, I can for example do this: "CREATE TABLE users_profile(user_id INTEGER UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT,\ ...."  and I get the exact same Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working. Foreign key reference needs to be the last thing.

Like this: `'CREATE TABLE users_profile(user_id INTEGER UNIQUE, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, email TEXT, website TEXT,\
        picture TEXT, mobile TEXT, skype TEXT, age INTEGER, residence TEXT, gender TEXT,\
        signature TEXT, avatar TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) \
        ON DELETE CASCADE)'`